# Matplotlib: cannot save PDF figure

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

I had to delete and re-install  again `matplotlib` a couple of times. Now, the modules work again, but I cannot save PDF figures. I get the following error:

```
No module named backend_pdf
```

I could try to remove matplotlib again and re-install. Can I just install the missing module?

Comment: No, you can't just install the missing backend. It is not a module.

Comment: what operating system and `matploblib` version are you using. How do you install `matplotlib`?

Comment: I am working on Ubuntu 12.04. The `matplotlib` version is '1.4.x'. I had it running, but I wanted to update the version. So, I uninstalled it, and installed it again following the [instructions](http://matplotlib.org/faq/installing_faq.html?highlight=installation#how-to-install). However, I installed twice trying to get the right version: I first used `git pull`, but the version was not what I was looking for. Then, I installed it again from source code [here](http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html) (1.2.1).

Answer (score 1):

The module it is referring to is an internal module in matplotlib; conceivably you could find the module on github and copy it to $MATPLOTLIBPATH/backends.  But yes, if reinstalling matplotlib is an option, I would try that, because that error is strange and who knows what else is missing.